# Cannot change navbar to fixed position

Tags: css, angular

I have a web app in angular, and I am trying to figure out what is ruling out the `div class container` to be in the center and have a specified width in size. I assume that it is in the bootstrap file as I cannot seem to find it and change it. The navigation bar is currently in the middle of the container and not in fixed position. Would like to know how to fix this.

This is the code I currently have for **nav.component.html**:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand">Kumo</a>    

      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active">
          <a class="nav-link waves-light" [routerLink]="['/home']" mdbWavesEffect>Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active">
          <a class="nav-link waves-light" [routerLink]="['/log-in']" mdbWavesEffect>Login</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active">
          <a class="nav-link waves-light" [routerLink]="['/sign-up']" mdbWavesEffect>Register</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active">
            <a class="nav-link waves-light" [routerLink]="['/order']" mdbWavesEffect>Order</a>
          </li>
        <li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active">
            <a class="nav-link waves-light" [routerLink]="['/cart']" mdbWavesEffect>Cart</a>
          </li>
         <li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active" style="float:right" *ngIf="role == '2'" >
            <a class="nav-link waves-light" [routerLink]="['/store']" mdbWavesEffect>Store</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active" style="float:right" *ngIf="role == '1'" >
          <a class="nav-link waves-light" [routerLink]="['/profile']" mdbWavesEffect>Profile</a>
      </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

The closest solution I could find is to change **nav.component.css** to this, but the problem here is that, whatever is in `<router-outlet>`, it is covering the navbar.:

```
.navbar {
     position: fixed;
     left: 0px; }
```

My **app.component.html** code has this:

```
<div class="container">
  <app-nav></app-nav>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Comment: you want your navbar to be always on top, right? Are you using bootstrap 3 or 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 solution to this problem, static and dynamic margin, when you say `position-fixed`, you need to apply `margin` to elements so that they can appear below the fixed element.

The problem with static approach is if somehow `height` of `navbar` changes then it wont work.

**1. Static `margin-top` (Simple)**

**app.component.html**

```html
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 62px">
  <app-nav (navHeight)="onNavHeight($event)"></app-nav>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

**2. Dynamic `margin-top` ([Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-axcyd9?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts))**

In this approach, first calculate the height of navbar and notify the parent with the height of navbar using `@Output`

Get reference of `navbar`, so that `height` can be used.

**nav.component.html**

```html
<nav #navbar class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
...
```

Get `height` from reference and notify parent about the `height`.

**nav.component.ts**

```js
export class NavComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output() navHeight: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter();
  @ViewChild('navbar') navbar: ElementRef;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.navHeight.next(this.navbar.nativeElement.offsetHeight);
  }
}
```

Add event so that event can be captured.

**app.component.html**

```html
<div class="container" [style.margin-top.px]="navbarTopMargin">
  <app-nav (navHeight)="onNavHeight($event)"></app-nav>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Get value from event and update the `margin-top` variable with received value.

**app.component.ts**

```js
export class AppComponent  {

  navbarTopMargin: number = 0;

  onNavHeight(topMargin: number) {
    console.log(topMargin);
    this.navbarTopMargin = topMargin;
  }
}
```